# Design Pattern for Local and Push notifications in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, design-patterns, notifications

I need to implement a flexible module to handle Local and Push notifications in Objective-C, this module needs to be flexible so it can be reusable and imported to other apps with minimun adjustments.

I have a few ideas but I would like to know if there is a design pattern that eases this implementation.

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the best patter is the **Command Pattern** using [NSInvocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsinvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html), so the notification can call a method and the invocator calls it on runtime. Any other suggestion??